# Query next epoch from postgresql

Tags: cardano-db-sync

How can I get the next Epoch.No using Postgresql. If I use

> 'SELECT no FROM epoch ORDER BY no desc limit 1'

, it returned last epoch/currentEpoch, if I want to receive the next Epoch.No, what should I do? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The epoch table is populated at the beginning of the epoch, actually more accurately at the first block received for that epoch. You can't get data that doesn't exist. If you're wondering what the next epoch is though, just take the result of that query and add 1.